# Create a Python jupyter code of the relation : means correlation using the the excel information https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlA0h7BjHqoZjRoaB9W6SVbvYmJX

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[image]

Find out if there is any relation between the tall of a football player and the number of shootings and dribblings.

Find out if there is any relation between the weight of a football player and the number of defendings and physics.

Based on the above results, give your interpretations.

[image]

Comment: find out the coorelation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.